# Laravel .env setup

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Laravel for quite some time now, but every time I want to migrate I have to change my `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1` And then if I want to see my webapp I have to change it back to `localhost` otherwise it will trow an exception:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I'm using homestead this is my homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: website.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/website/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

My `/hosts/etc` file:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   website.dev
```

When I ping `localhost` I receive:

```
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
```

I really need to fix this. Please some help!

Comment: It says that can't connect to the database. You wrote right in the title, but did'nt post your `.env`, show us!

Comment: The database user must have rights on both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. I'm pretty sure it has only on localhost right now..

Comment: Be aware that homestead uses `33060` port on `127.0.0.1` for mysql, even if it should work this way *only* from outside the vm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database user must have rights on both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. I'm pretty sure it has only on localhost right now.

Comment: thanks for your reaction. When I want to give permissions for that in mysql. I login with ssh: vagrant@homestead and then mysql -u homestead -p and then GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'vagrant'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION but that's not working what should I do?

Comment: Made a new question about that.